# route same url to different controllers based on method in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm trying to have the following structure

```
get  /something/id/apply => controller 1
post /something/id/apply => controller 2
```

is there an easy way to accomplish this in rails 2.x? right now i'm resorting to manually checking the http method in the controller code, and that seems... fugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  map.match '/something/:id/apply', :method => :get, :controller => 'controller1'
  map.match '/something/:id/apply', :method => :post, :controller => 'controller2'
```

Comment: Yes, but he has the correct method, just needs to cleanup his copy/pasting :)

Comment: Yes I clean with controller 2 in second line